# Tokenize math expressions without importing any module in python

Tags: python, token, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize math expression including integers, floats (both positive and negative) with operators and brackets.

For example,

```
expression = "-2.56*13.2+(11/-4)-.55"
tokenize(expression)
["-2.56", "*", "13.2", "+", "(", "11", "/", "-4", ")", "-", ".55"]
```

My attempt:

```
def tokenize(expression):
    tokens = []
    for char in expression:
    if char.isdigit() and tokens[-1].isdigit():
        tokens[-1] += char
    else:
        tokens.append(char)
    return tokens

expression2 = "((12+13)*5)"
tokenize(expression2)
['(', '(', '12', '+', '13', ')', '*', '5', ')']
```

My code works for expression that starts with brackets but not those which aren't and also does not work with negative sign and floats. Without importing any modules, how should I tokenize expressions with positive and negative floats? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please fix the code's indentation

Comment: This is a pretty difficult problem to tackle without at least the `re` module (and using something designed for actual language parsing would be better).  The ambiguity of minus signs in particular makes it a lot trickier than simply fixing how you classify each individual character.  Why the "without importing any modules" requirement?  If it's for a course, they're throwing you in the deep end too early, and I recommend dropping it and finding a more beginner-appropriate course.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple table that can decide, based on an input character and a preceeding character, whether or not to return the current character expression you have, or continue to accumulate characters:

```
d = {'-':[lambda x:x.isdigit() or x == ')', lambda x:x.isdigit() or x == '('], '(':True, ')':True, '*':[lambda x:x.isdigit() or x == ')', lambda x:x.isdigit() or x == '('], '+':[lambda x:x.isdigit() or x == ')', lambda x:x.isdigit() or x == '('], '/':[lambda x:x.isdigit() or x == ')', lambda x:x.isdigit() or x in ['-', '(']]}
def tokenize(s):
   l, r = None, None
   while s:
      t, s = s[0], s[1:]
      if t not in d:
         r, l = t if r is None else r+t, t
      else:
         if (f:=isinstance(d[t], list)) and not s: #need lookahead, but have reached eof
            raise Exception('tokenization error')
         if (f and l and d[t][0](l) and d[t][1](s[0])) or (not f and d[t]):
            yield r
            yield t
            r, l = None, t
         else:
            r, l = t if r is None else r + t, t     
   if r is not None:
       yield r

exprs = ["-2.56*13.2+(11/-4)-.55", "((12+13)*5)", '-3', '(-1.4)', '(4/5)*4+(-1)*(4+(3-2))']
r = [list(filter(None, tokenize(i))) for i in exprs]
```

Output:

```
[['-2.56', '*', '13.2', '+', '(', '11', '/', '-4', ')', '-.55'], ['(', '(', '12', '+', '13', ')', '*', '5', ')'], ['-3'], ['(', '-1.4', ')'], ['(', '4', '/', '5', ')', '*', '4', '+', '(', '-1', ')', '*', '(', '4', '+', '(', '3', '-', '2', ')', ')']]
```

Comment: thank you for you answer. as stated in the question, I am not allowed to import anything. things are much more easier if I am allowed to do so...